# Django: User login not works for some users

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm currently learning django. Here is my problem: user created using terminal with createsuperuser can log in to the website, but users created with my register page are not. Users created using my registration appear in the admin panel and all fields match the entered data. I guess the problem is somewhere in CustomUserManager(before creating it login worked properly)

> models.py

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, first_name, bio, password, **other_fields):
        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must be assigned staff to True")
        
        if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must be assigned superuser to True")

        return self.create_user(email, username, first_name, bio, password, **other_fields)

    def create_user(self, email, username, first_name, bio, password, **other_fields):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError("You must provide an email.")

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, username=username, first_name=first_name, bio=bio,
                           **other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, verbose_name="Имя")
    username = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, null=True, verbose_name="Никнейм", unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, unique=True)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True, default="avatar.svg", blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name','username','bio']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

> views.py

```
def loginPage(request):
    page = 'login'
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email').lower()
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
            print(user)
        except:
            messages.error(request, 'User does not exist.')
        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Username or password does not exist.')

    context = {'page': page}
    return render(request, 'base/login_register.html', context)




def registerPage(request):
    form = MyUserCreationForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.username = user.username.lower()
            user.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'An error occured during registration.')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'base/login_register.html', context)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `User` model class you set `is_active` default value to `False`

```
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

So your user is not `active` when created from `registerPage` view.

The default backend [ModelBackend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend) and [RemoteUserBackend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend) prohibits the inactive users from authenticating. Since you are `authenticating` user from django `default` `authentication` it always returns `None`.

If you want all user's you created to set `is_active` to True for all users then you can set `default` to True.

```
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Otherwise you can add logic in your `views.py` to set `is_active` to True if some condition `success`

```
def registerPage(request):
    form = MyUserCreationForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.username = user.username.lower()
            if active_true_condition: #<--- if condition true set True
                user.is_active = True
            user.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'An error occured during registration.')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'base/login_register.html', context)
```

And set `default` to False in this `case`.

Answer (score 2):

In your `User` models set:

```
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```